# FTP connections stack up even though number of simultaneous connections are limited to 1

Tags: web-hosting, ftp, filezilla

I have a big problem with using FTP.

When I try to transfer a large amount of files after a little time I get the error:

`421 Too many connections (8) from this IP`

In FileZilla, I have set the number of simultaneous connections for this account as 1 and have no other FTP clients connected to it.

I've checked FTP Session Control in CPanel and can see the connections stacking up. I must manually sit there and disconnect the older connections to upload a large amount of files.

Would anyone know what I can do to fix this?

I am using FileZilla and have tried on several different machines

UPDATE: I believe this is to do with my ISP - I have tried in another location and it seems fine

Comment: Who owns the server?

Comment: @DaveRook hosting company VentraIP

Comment: ...then contact them? also, see if the issue exists work another FTP program

Answer (score 0):

Found it was an issue with my ISP having 'micro' drop outs. Connection would be lost for a second so the FTP client would reconnect and for some reason the connections would stack up causing me this issue